# Mapping between ImageNet and Wikidata entities

Tags: data-request, wikidata, data-mapping, imagenet

Wikidata and ImageNet both know oxcarts:

- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1190777
- http://imagenet.stanford.edu/synset?wnid=n03868242 (slow)

An AI library gives me the ImageNet "synset" about oxcarts.

From this "synset", how to get the equivalent Wikidata item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to see [ImageNet to Wikidata mapping](https://github.com/DominikFilipiak/imagenet-to-wikidata-mapping) (I am the co-author), which extends the work of Finn Arup Nielsen.

> We linked the ILSVRC 2012 dataset (often simply referred as ImageNet) labels to Wikidata entities. This enables using rich knowledge graph structure and contextual information for several computer vision tasks, traditionally benchmarked with ImageNet and its variations. We mapped all 1000 ImageNet labels - 461 were already directly linked with the exact match property (P2888), 467 have exact match candidates, and 72 cannot be matched directly. For these 72 labels, we proposed semantically close non-exact match candidates are presented as well.

More details [in the paper](https://www.tib-op.org/ojs/index.php/bis/article/view/65).

Answer (score 3):

I have used the [P2888](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2888) property for linking WordNet synset URIs with Wikidata item, and as pointed out by Stanislav Kralin written about it in the article *[Linking ImageNet WordNet Synsets with Wikidata](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/7090/pdf/imm7090.pdf)*.

Provided that the URI is available with the P2888 property, you may then query with the Wikidata Query Service at https://query.wikidata.org. For instance, with string "n03868242" (oxcart) embedded in the SPARQL:

```
SELECT 
  ?item
  ?uri
WHERE {
  BIND(URI(CONCAT("http://wordnet-rdf.princeton.edu/wn30/", SUBSTR("n03868242", 2), "-n")) AS ?uri)
  ?item wdt:P2888 ?uri . 
}
```

Wikidata Query Service link: http://tinyurl.com/y7eeo78p

Currently, there are 475 linked items (http://tinyurl.com/y9s26qm6), so the mapping is not complete.

Also note that I do not think we have reached consensus on how this mapping should be done, e.g., see the discussion at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Talk:Q1190777.

Comment: I modified your query to also output each item's label and Commons category if available: https://w.wiki/5Y2

Answer (score 2):

ImageNet more or less [consistently](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/12309/consistency-of-imagenet-labeling-wrt-wordnet) uses WordNet synset IDs.
There is the *Wordnet synset ID* [property proposal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Property_proposal/Wordnet_synset_ID) on Wikidata.

Currently, the only option available is to use BabelNet which has WordNet as one of the  sources.

[This page](http://live.babelnet.org/about) mentions Wikidata as another source, but I can find DBpedia entities only with BabelNet SPARQL endpoint. Probably this means:

- one should use known DBpedia-Wikidata mappings;
- one should use the *BabelNet Id* Wikidata property (~ 60 000 uses in Wikidata).

---

See  @FinnÅrupNielsen's [article](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/7090/pdf/imm7090.pdf) for interesting details.

Comment: This proposal has been withdrawn.

Comment: So, your proposed solution is to: 1) From the ImageNet "synset", get the BabelNet id 2) From the BabelNet id, see whether a Wikidata item has it 3) If there is none, see if a DBpedia item has it. Am I understanding correctly? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the PDF, the title sounds like it was written exactly to address my problem!